# Can a convex function be uniformly approximated by convex combination of simpler convex functions?

Tags: convex-analysis, approximation-theory

According to [universal approximation theorem](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/acta-numerica/article/abs/approximation-theory-of-the-mlp-model-in-neural-networks/18072C558C8410C4F92A82BCC8FC8CF9), any continuous function can be uniformly approximated by neural network with single hidden layer.

Similarly, can a convex function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be uniformly approximated by convex combination of simpler convex functions?

Or, is there any analysis on the collection of convex functions?

Comment: Although there are simple results for convex functions $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, including [sum of $|x-a_i|$](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1911/42/0/42_0_311/_pdf) and [a modified version](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1149860218),
it is hard to find the results about convex functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Define "simpler", please.

Comment: @ProfessorVector For example, as the extension of one dimensional case, $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be uniformly approximated by $\sum_{i=1}^{m} c_i |a_i^T x + b_i|$?
Sorry for my poor question. I wonder if there is a neural network which approximates any convex function and is also convex in its argument.

Comment: You can always approximate a convex function by a piecewise-affine function, though the number of affine pieces you need will likely depend on the function you are approximating.

Comment: @VHarisop Thanks.
To the best knowledge of me, the piecewise-affine is constructed by pointwise-maximum as described in [this](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v38/balazs15.html).
Can the piecewise-affine approximator be represented as a sum of affine functions like a normal layer of feedforward neural network?

Comment: @JinraeKim: The sum of affine functions is also affine, so you can't represent the piecewise-affine structure without using a nonlinear operation. If you are interested in architectures, you might want to take a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07850).

Comment: @VHarisop Thanks a lot :) I'll loot at it.